# Using the same tcp client from 2 different forms

Tags: c#, winforms, tcpclient

I am creating a tcpClient on my main form and i am reading and writing to an irc server.

```
tcpClient = new TcpClient(serverName, 6667);
reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
writer = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());
writer.AutoFlush = true;
```

at some point my app opens a second form with a listbox of some options and i want to double click on one of these options and write something to the initial stream. I have tried creating a new tcpClient on the same port with a new reader and writer but this does not seem to work.

```
    private void listBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SendMessage("some message");
    }

    private void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient;
        StreamReader reader;
        StreamWriter writer;            
        string serverName = "chicago.il.us.undernet.org";
        tcpClient = new TcpClient(serverName, 6667);
        reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
        writer = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());
        writer.AutoFlush = true;
        writer.WriteLine("PRIVMSG #chan :" + message + "\r\n");

    }
```

Could anybody point me to the right direction please?

Comment: you can't have 2 processes running on the same port. Share the same instance of the TcpClient between your forms. Designing a wrapper class using the Singleton Pattern might be one way to achieve this neatly.

Comment: It's right there in the title of your question: _"Using the same tcp client from 2 different forms"_. I.e. **use the same `TcpClient` object in both forms.** Now, there's no sign in the code you posted that you've made any effort to do that, nor any effort to research _how_ you might do that. Please improve the question, and make sure you explain _specifically_ what you need help with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the reason I did not make any effort is because i do not know how. This is why i am asking for someone to "point me to the right direction". And how could you possibly know about the effort i already made to research before i ended up posting here? Perhaps it is my limited knowledge of c# that will not allow me to ask the right question or do the proper google search.

Comment: _"how could you possibly know about the effort i already made to research"_ -- traditionally, the way one would know is that your post _would describe that effort_. Note that I didn't say you did no research; I simply pointed out that your question has no evidence that you did. As for the question itself, it's not clear whether you know enough about OOP in general...you may or may not be asking a Winforms/TcpClient question. If you had two instances of class `A`, and wanted to provide one of those instances with a reference to an instance of class `B` that the other made, could you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you I am not an expert in C#, I only program as a hobby and I'm self taught. So maybe there is a better way to do this, but this is how I would approach it myself.

Add a new class to your project like this:

```
namespace Test //If you copy this, remember to change the namespace to match your application
{
    class Shared
    {
        public static TcpClient client = new TcpClient(“server”, 6667);

        //OR do this and use the Connect method to connect later (see below)
        public static TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    }
}
```

If you use the second declaration you could then connect later from ANY form (you would only need to connect once) when the form loads or on a button click etc. using this:

```
Shared.client.Connect(serverName, 6667);
```

Then in both of your forms you can do the following. Or if the SendMessage() function would be the same for both forms you could always make it a static function in the Shared class and call `Shared.SendMessage("your message");`.

```
private void SendMessage(string message)
{

    if (Shared.client.Connected)
    {
        StreamReader reader;
        StreamWriter writer;

        reader = new StreamReader(Shared.client.GetStream());
        writer = new StreamWriter(Shared.client.GetStream());
        writer.AutoFlush = true;
        writer.WriteLine("PRIVMSG #chan :" + message + "\r\n");
    }

}
```

Using `static` to declare `client` in the `Shared` class means that it is not referenced by an instance of the class. So you don't have to do `Shared sharedClass = new Shared();` before you can access it, and if you made 2 instances of the Shared class `client` would only have one instance which is accessible to both instances of the class.

Comment: i have been away from my pc and have not been able to test this out yet. just one question. do i need to connect the shared.client every time i need to send a message?

Comment: That’s a good point, no you don’t. You only need to connect once. I’ve edited my answer to show two options for connecting. It would be worth using the IF statement I suggested every time you send a message in that case. I will edit the question to include that in SendMessage() tomorrow. It’s a little difficult on my phone :)

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the IF statement and make things a bit clearer.